# C++ template return type for an abstract method (similar to java)

Tags: c++, templates

Let say I have a visitor in Java.

```java
interface Visitor<T> {
    T visitA(VisitableA a);
    T visitB(VisitableB b);
}

abstract class Visitable {
    abstract <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}

class VisitableA extends Visitable {
    @Override <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitA(this);
    }
}

class VisitableB extends Visitable {
    @Override <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitB(this);
    }
}
```

Now, if I wanted to take that and write it in C++, I could do it like this

```cpp
class VisitableA;
class VisitableB;

template <typename T> class Visitor {
    virtual T visitA(VisitableA& a) = 0;
    virtual T visitB(VisitableB& b) = 0;
};

class MyVisitor : public Visitor<int> {
    int visitA(VisitableA& a) override { /* do something */ return 42; }
    int visitB(VisitableB& b) override { /* do something */ return 1337; }
};

class Visitable {
    template <typename T> virtual T accept(Visitor<T>& visitor) = 0;
};

class VisitableA : public Visitable { 
    template <typename T> T accept(Visitor<T>& visitor) override { return visitor.visitA(*this); }
};

class VisitableB : public Visitable { 
    template <typename T> T accept(Visitor<T>& visitor) override { return visitor.visitB(*this); }
};
```

But this does not compile, since I cannot have a virtual templated method.

I could use `std::any` (or something similar) but I was wondering if there was a way do implement this without it.

It must be noted that the `accept` return type is not known at the construction of the `Visitable`s.

C++20 is fine if required.

Comment: You should look into [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Comment: I'm not sure it covers your needs, so not posting it as an answer :) Thinking about something like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/360b637d72fdb811

Comment: Hmm, the `Visitable`s are in fact nodes in a tree and the `visit` function follows the children in a manner depending on the type, I'm not exactly sure that would fit in that case, but I might give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what Java does under the hood.

Replace `T` with `std::any`.

For `Visitable` make a base class that returns `any` to both methods.  Then make a template class that implements the `any` returning as `final`, and creates a `T` returning `Visit` as pure for implementors to implement.

`Visitable` has two methods; a pure virtual private one taking a `Visitable`, and a public template taking a `VitiableT` template.  It calls the pure virtual one and casts the `any` to a `T`.

Java generics are basically just writing that glue for you.

You may have to do casting under the hood, or look at typeids, depending on how you use this.

```
struct VistableA; struct VistableB;
struct Visitor{
  virtual std::any visitA(VisitableA&)=0;
  virtual std::any visitB(VisitableB&)=0;
};
template<class T>
struct VisitorT:Visitor{
  std::any visitA(VisitableA& a) final{ return visitTA(a); }
  T visitTA(VisitableA& a) = 0;
  std::any visitB(VisitableB& b) final{ return visitTB(b); }
  T visitTB(VisitableB& b) = 0;
};

class MyVisitor : public VisitorT<int> {
  int visitTA(VisitableA& a) override { /* do something */ return 42; }
  int visitTB(VisitableB& b) override { /* do something */ return 1337; }
};

class Visitable {
  template <typename T>  T accept(VisitorT<T>& visitor) {
    return std::any_cast<T>(accept(static_cast<Visitor&>(visitor)));
  }
  virtual std::any accept(Visitor& visitor)=0;
};

class VisitableA : public Visitable { 
  std::any accept(Visitor& visitor) override { return visitor.visitA(*this); }
};

class VisitableB : public Visitable { 
  std::any accept(Visitor& visitor) override { return visitor.visitB(*this); }
};
```

now this being C++ there are another half dozen ways to solve your problem that do not emulate Java.  But this is the Java esque way.

Note because we are writing the glue code Java writes for you, if we make a mistake in the glue we aren't type safe.

And in `VisitableA` Java checks that the same "generic type" is used for all of the `T`s; in C++ I used a `std::any`, which could be mixed up with other "generics" and break some type safety.  You could imagine a complex system of tagged `std::any` to avoid this.

Comment: That's exactly my current implementation, and why I added "I could do it with `std::any` but I was wondering if there was another way". Maybe more typesafe indeed as you pointed out.

Comment: @zouch A variation of this is what Java does.  If you want what Java does, you implement what Java did (or something equivalent).  If your problem space differs in any sense from what Java solves, there are other solutions; piles of them.  You described your problem as what Java does, so I solved the problem you described.  Your real problem may be different, but you didn't describe your real problem, and I cannot read your mind.

Comment: @zouch you'll note that the code I wrote above wraps the T accepting and producing code, so most code does not care about the `any` layer.  If the set of types is bounded and enumerable, variant can work.  If the set of operations is bounded and enumerable, type erasure can work.  If bith are unbounded/unenumerable, then dynamic typing of some kind is required.

Comment: For some reason I actually did not see the wrapped types. This indeed looks like a solution. mb